# Angular SSR app cache only one http request

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I'm currently developing an Angular app with Server-Side Rendering (SSR), and we've recently upgraded to version 17.

Our challenge lies in making multiple HTTP POST requests (GraphQL) on a single page. However, upon page rehydration in the browser, we encounter an issue where all the responses turn out identical. It appears that the response is consistently derived from one of the requests, and the choice of which response is selected seems to be random.

Comment: Do you have the issue when you use `withNoHttpTransferCache()` ?

Comment: using withNoHttpTransferCache works fine, as expected

Comment: transfer cache is caching every GET request made to the backend to prevent sending them again when doing CSR. Are your request different ?

Comment: the requests are made to the same url, but with a diferent payload.

Comment: I am actually facing the same problem. I filed an issue to Angular team here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/54377.